# Массив строк СИ

Tags: c, строки

У меня есть массив строк, я этот массив заполняю строками, но если я хочу вывести первую строку то выводится и вторая строка. Что у меня не так?

```
int i,j;
    char mat[3][3];

    gets(mat[0]);
    gets(mat[1]);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(mat[i]);j++){
            printf("%c",mat[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }`
```

Comment: И где вы выводите 1-ю строку? А также используйте `fgets` вместо `gets`

Comment: Вы заводили длинные строки, шло переполнение. Как и говорили : `fgets(mat[0],3,stdin);`